# Check for not null condition and assign a value to that field in an array using Jolt Spec

Tags: json, jolt

Input JSON1 :

```json
{
  "task": {
    "external_id": "2023-03-22-13-15-18-184000",
    "way_points": [
      {
        "address": "Warminster Road",
        "position": 1,
        "eta": null
      },
      {
        "address": "7 John Rennie Close",
        "position": 2,
        "eta": "2023-03-22T13:33:54.827Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "webhook_type": "driver_on_the_way",
  "merchant_id": 60470
}
```

Output JSON1:

```json
{
  "shipper" : 60470,
  "shipmentId" : "externalId",
  "messages" : [ {
    "eta" : "2023-03-22T13:33:54.827Z",
    "messageType" : "STOP_ETA_UPDATE",
    "message" : "driver_on_the_way"
  } ]
}
```

Input JSON2 :

```json
{
  "task": {
    "external_id": "2023-03-22-13-15-18-184000",
    "way_points": [
      {
        "address": "Warminster Road",
        "position": 1,
        "eta": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "webhook_type": "driver_on_the_way",
  "merchant_id": 60470
}
```

Output JSON2:

```json
{
  "shipper" : 60470,
  "shipmentId" : "externalId",
  "messages" : [ {
    "eta" : "2023-03-22T13:33:54.827Z",
    "messageType" : "TRACKING_UPDATE",
    "message" : "driver_on_the_way"
  } ]
}
```

**Description:**
There are 2 positions :  1 and 2 in the way_points list. There is a possibility that only position : 1 can be present or both positions : 1 and 2 can be present. Now, if position : 2 is present and eta is not null, then messageType = 'STOP_ETA_UPDATE' but if position : 2 is not present then messageType = 'TRACKING_UPDATE'

Jolt Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "task": {
        "way_points": {
          "*": {
            "position": {
              "2": {
                "eta": {
                  "|null": null,
                  "#TRACKING_UPDATE": "messageType1",
                  "*": {
                    "#STOP_ETA_UPDATE": "messageType1"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following ***lastElement*** function to grab the object labeled with the highest position ( as there might exist **1** or **2**)  after sorting them based on those labels such as

```json
[
  { // determine the cases for the conditional that will be used in the next step
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "task": {
        "way_points": {
          "*": {
            "eta_": ["=isNull(@(1,eta))", "Notnull"], // if "eta" is not null, then assign "Notnull"
            "new_val": "=concat(@(1,position),'_',@(1,eta_))"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "merchant_id": "shipper",
      "#externalId": "shipmentId",
      "task": {
        "way_points": {
          "*": {
            "new_val": {
              "2_Notnull": {
                "#STOP_ETA_UPDATE": "&5.@3,position.messageType",
                "@2,eta": "&5.@3,position.eta"
              },
              "*": {
                "#TRACKING_UPDATE": "&5.@3,position.messageType",
                "@2,eta": "&5.@3,position.eta"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "task": {
        "*": "messages[]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "messages": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "messages": "&[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That was very helpful. However, I was expecting if position 2 is present and eta is not null, then messageType = STOP_ETA_UPDATE else if positon 2 is not present then messageType = TRACKING_UPDATE

Comment: Hi @rashmin you're welcome, just fixed the answer.

Comment: for the same input json, the corrected jolt spec is giving below output :{
  "messages" : [ {
    "messageType" : "TRACKING_UPDATE",
    "eta" : null
  }, {
    "messageType" : "STOP_ETA_UPDATE",
    "eta" : "2023-03-22T13:33:54.827Z"
  } ]
}
But I want only 1 messageType at a time.

Comment: But there are more than one values for positions, and multiple eta attributes as well. Can you please make the cases clearer by editing the question in order to state what exactly you need @rashmin

Comment: There are 2 positions : 1 and 2 in the way_points list. There is a possibility that only position : 1 can be present or both positions : 1 and 2 can be present. Postion : 1 is present by default. Now, if position : 2 is present and eta is not null, then messageType = 'STOP_ETA_UPDATE' but if position : 2 is not present then messageType = 'TRACKING_UPDATE'

Comment: @rashmin There's only single input and desired output yet(expected at least to be two of them with each pairs described separately ). Btw, no need to mention the details here, just use to notify me through comments.

Comment: I have updated the input json and desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @barbaros, that worked.. :) I was struggling for this for almost a week.

Comment: 1 last questions: what if I had to extra fields into the output json? where to add them? the input and output jsons are edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot @barbaros. :) This was very helpful. Got my questions answered... :)